# how to set placeholders in like statement query

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

I am creating a `PreparedStatement` with SQL which have a `like` statement, and I am setting the placeholders using `setString()`, method, but it does not give any error or fetch any records. When I run the query direct at database by setting arguments in like statements then I get results, so I think there may be any other way to put place holders in sql, I am doing like below:

```
select name from employee where name like ?
```

I also tried:

```
select name from employee where name like (?)
```

and set parameters using `setString()` method but I did not get any results.

Please help what is wrong in it

Comment: can you show a little more code?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857164/cannot-use-a-like-query-in-a-jdbc-prepared-statement

Comment: What string are you passing into the setString() method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the way by which you used it first. If you need another post which explains this, please see:

[Cannot use a LIKE query in a JDBC PreparedStatement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857164/cannot-use-a-like-query-in-a-jdbc-prepared-statement)

Answer (score 2):

this is an example from API:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE EMPLOYEES
                                     SET SALARY = ? WHERE ID = ?");
   // set the first (?)
   pstmt.setBigDecimal(1, 153833.00)
   // set the second (?)
   pstmt.setInt(2, 110592)
```

you can see more in : http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html

Comment: is it also same for like statement