# Spring JDBC template sorting

Tags: sorting, spring-mvc, jdbctemplate

I'm trying to implement sorting and pagination on server side in my spring mvc application.

The problem is that after call `JdbcTemplate.query()` method I get unsorted array list.

My query code:

```
List<Ingredient> ingredients = query("SELECT * FROM Ingredients ORDER BY ? ? LIMIT ?, ?",
                new Object[]{"title", "ASC", 0, 50},
                new IngredientsMapper());
```

My mapper code:

```
public class IngredientsMapper implements ParameterizedRowMapper {

    @Override
    public Ingredient mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        Ingredient ingredient = new Ingredient();
        ingredient.setId(rs.getInt("IngredientID"));
        ingredient.setTitle(rs.getString("title"));
        ingredient.setCost(rs.getFloat("cost"));
        ingredient.setDescription(rs.getString("description"));
        ingredient.setUnits(rs.getString("units"));
        return ingredient;
    }
}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for any help. Have a good day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a parameter to refer to column values. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2857417/404536) for details.