# Usage of ? within prepared statement

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot use a Like query in a JDBC prepared statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857164/cannot-use-a-like-query-in-a-jdbc-prepared-statement)

Is it possible to prepare a SQL statement like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(?) FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMUN_1 LIKE '%?%'
```

and in Java,

```
preparedStmt.setString(1, "COLUMN_2");
preparedStmt.setString(2, "FORD");
```

Comment: The answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857164/cannot-use-a-like-query-in-a-jdbc-prepared-statement answers this question perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Nope.  As a general rule, you can only use placeholders for values, not identifiers like table and column names.