# How to can we add order by in PreparedStatement?

Tags: java, prepared-statement

I have to create a prepared statement to fetch data from MqSQL db.

I could not find a way to add order by in `preparedstatement` way..
I have append order by info in sql string before creating `preparedstatement`.

However client quality tool reported this as an sql injection.Since we are added order by info(ie.asc/desc) from a variable.

Is their any alternative.Could you please help me ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857164/cannot-use-a-like-query-in-a-jdbc-prepared-statement/2857417#2857417), perhaps of some help.

Answer (score 2):

Pass asc/desc as a parameter to the method and use it in the query string.