# MySQL order by name desc query in prepared statement

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I am using this 1st query still cannot achieve what i want:

```
PreparedStatement id = con.prepareStatement("select c_id from customer where c_name=? ORDER by c_name desc ");
id.setString(1,m.getName());
```

I have a JSP form which is filling the (MySQL)customer table and `c_id` is only auto-incremented when the form is submitted on button click, but on submission, I want to do another thing which is to **select latest entry of c_id** which is filled in the table. Due to submission of an entry, a new auto-incremented c_id has been generated which I am getting through this query which is alright.

```
PreparedStatement id = con.prepareStatement("select c_id from customer where c_name=? ");
id.setString(1,m.getName());
```

Now the problem is that the (1st or 2nd)query gets the `c_id` by looking at `c_name`, if the `c_name` was never present in the table and has been entered the first time then it will surely get the latest `c_id` by looking at `c_name`, but what if the `c_name` was already present.

For example:
If customer has `c_id` `10` and `c_name` `jacob` and if I entered the query for the first time I am able to select `c_id` `10` but now if I try to enter another entry having `c_id` `11` and `c_name` `jacob` I still get the `c_id` `10` here and here what I want is `c_id` `11` which is latest entered having same `c_name`.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You can refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857164/cannot-use-a-like-query-in-a-jdbc-preparedstatement/2857417#2857417

Comment: MySQL has a `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function that will get the ID of the last record created. I think it will only work if you use the same connection that you used to do the insert (ie don't close the connection after the insert).

Comment: It worked for me by using this :                                                                                         
PreparedStatement id = con.prepareStatement("select c_id from customer where c_name=? ORDER by c_id desc "); id.setString(1,m.getName());

Comment: That might become a problem. If Dave inserts a record for customer 1 and a millisecond later Suzy also inserts a record for customer 1, there is a good chance that your query to get the ID will find Suzy's record twice.