# Cannot put value into SQL Statement in Java Spring Boot

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

I have `private static final String SQL_SEARCH_ALL = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE name LIKE '%?%'";` SQL statement, where I need to pass a query String. When instead of `?` mark I pass a string like `'%cola%'` it works fine.

I pass paramater using JdbcTemplate as I have used to

```
return jdbcTemplate.query(SQL_SEARCH_ALL, new Object[]{searchInput}, productRowMapper);
```

That returns zero objects.

I have problem with passing value into this statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JDBC parameters are not strings that are replaced anywhere you use a `?` marker; that would open the query to SQL Injection. Depending on each database and each JDBC driver the allowed locations for a `?` parameter marker vary.

It's safe to say a parameter can usually go where a typical literal value can go, but it's not always the case. For example, in DB2 the clause `FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY` does not accept a `?` instead of the literal `5`.

In your case, the typical solution is to use `CONCAT()`. For example:

```
private static final String SQL_SEARCH_ALL =
  "SELECT * FROM product WHERE name LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')";
```

Of course you need to decide what do you want to happen is a null parameter is provided. Probably a `COALESCE()` function is in order there.

Comment: This might not work, because you are trying to concatenate a wildcard `?` placeholder to `%` on both sides.  Instead, a single `?` placeholder should be used here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm not sure what you're talking about. The statement will work fine, if e.g. `ps.setString(1, "lamp");` is used, then it'll find any product where `lamp` shows up anywhere in its `name` column, and every JDBC library I know of allows a `?` in that position.

Comment: @rzwitserloot [This question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857164/cannot-use-a-like-query-in-a-jdbc-preparedstatement) do not agree with your previous comment.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen You have misunderstood that answer. Go try it out, it works fine.

Comment: @rzwitserloot I just used the Lombok library for a small Spring Boot project.  Nice stuff, it helps to keep my Java code as minimal as possible.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way of doing this in Java (or really any language) is to use a single `?` placeholder and then bind the wildcard expression to that placeholder:

```java
private static final String SQL_SEARCH_ALL = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE name LIKE ?";
String searchInput = "%cola%";
return jdbcTemplate.query(SQL_SEARCH_ALL, new Object[]{ searchInput }, productRowMapper);
```